# Unable to create an active directory inside windows server 2016 inside vmware workstation

Tags: active-directory, vmware-workstation

I am a software developer and i want to test my asp.net core MVC web application to integrate with active directory using LDAP. since i am using Windows 10 home edition so i can not create a test AD inside my windows 10 home edition. so i did the following:-

1. inside my windows 10 home edition >> i installed vmware workstation
2. download windows server 2016 datacenter iso image.
3. I install windows server 2016 inside the vmware workstation.

then i enable all those roles and features:-

[image]

the VM got this domain name "WIN-O0DSF1PFVD9" >> I restarted my VM >> but when i tired to configure my VM (mainly prompt this server to domain), i got this error:-

[image]

[image]

any advice how i can define AD and define LDAP string for this windows server 2016? to test my code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have VMware workstation, you can follow this step how to configure ADDS, you can also use this link [Install Active Directory Domain Services in Windows Server](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-active-directory-domain-services-in-windows-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new Domain and Forest, not adding a Domain Controller to an existing Domain. You need to select the third option in the Deployment Configuration.

https://www.ittsystems.com/active-directory-setup-guide/#wbounce-modal